# AKTableView issue 100% CPU usage

Tags: audiokit

I'm trying to assign a table view to an already existing UIView object on my storyboard but every time I assign it by specifying the correct frame I get an issue.

```
let sampleTable = AKTableView(AKTable(file: sampleReferences[indexPath.row].sampleFile!), frame: samplePlot.bounds)
        samplePlot.addSubview(sampleTable)
```

This is the code I'm using at the moment. I've also used samplePlot.frame.
Basically the sampleReferences[indexPath.row].sampleFile! is an AKAudioFile stored earlier from a recording stored as a reference from a UITableView element. It's quite a large program split into multiple files so it's hard to show everything.
The only extra issue I can think of is I haven't stopped any of the current AudioKit processes. I'm not sure if the table can only be drawn at startup.

The following works with a .sine specifier AKTable(.sine) so it's not an issue with my UI code. It also fails when trying to load even a basic .mp3 file from .resources.

**Update:**
I've compressed the test .mp3 file significatly and shortened it's overall length to 2 seconds and I'm still getting the same issue. I think it might be an issue with the actual function used to draw the file. Although I could be wrong.

**Another update:**
So everything works fine using the following code

```
let file = EZAudioFile(url: sampleAudio!.url)
        guard let data = file?.getWaveformData() else {
            print("Failed to get waveform data")
            return }

        let waveform = EZAudioPlot()
        waveform.frame = samplePlot.bounds
        waveform.plotType = EZPlotType.buffer
        waveform.shouldFill = true
        waveform.shouldMirror = true
        waveform.color = UIColor.black
        waveform.updateBuffer(data.buffers[0], withBufferSize: data.bufferSize )
        samplePlot.addSubview(waveform)
```

but obviously I'm using EZAudioPlot. I grabbed this from a previous stack overflow issue for the same thing and edited it a bit.